# How can you schedule regular tasks to execute when available?

Tags: cron, schedule

I want to schedule some tasks on my ubuntu 20.04 destkop to execute regularly. Like backups or downloads from certain sites or whatever.

I have been using `crontab` for this, but if so happens that my computer is not powered at that time, it will just not do them.

How can I schedule a task to run, lets say, every saturday at 12.00pm or whenever the computer is back online after that date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible alternatives to `cron` would be `anacron` or `systemd timers`. With both solutions, you can trigger jobs at certain times and configure what to do, when a scheduled job has been missed.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I had heard about `anacron` before but I couldn't remember what it was called or how to find out!